# Csv file maximum size that can be imported in h2o

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, h2o, h2o4gpu

What is the external  CSV file maximum size that can be imported in h2o Flow?is there any file size limit?

Thanks
Sarvendra

Answer (score 0):

H2O-3 does not have any specific file size limit.

Since the data is stored in-memory, the practical limit is directly correlated to the amount of memory you have.  You can add more nodes, or more memory to the existing nodes you have, to work with larger datasets.

For example, a billion rows with terabyte of total data is fine if you have the hardware to handle it.

Comment: We have approximately 70 million records(around 90 GB Data) and we need to ingest in h2o and then we need to do modeling in h2o.  Please suggest the approximate h2o distributed environment we need to create..like Heapsize, Number of nodes instances, Nodes configuration and how will multiple instances will communicate..As we need to give estimation to our client..So please suggest these configurations.

Comment: I recommend accepting the answer to this question and creating a new question.